# Typo3 8.7.x / Typoscript: Can't get added field in table pages

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-8.x

anybody knows why I can't get my field tx_myext_myfield added to table pages with typoscript?

Typoscript

```
test = TEXT
test {
    datawrap = My field: {levelfield : -1 , tx_myext_myfield, slide}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get the value of the user defined field user_myExtField in the root line. Requires additional configuration in $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] to include field.:`

From the documentation

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Index.html?highlight=addrootlinefield#levelfield